# C++ 2-dimensional Array Size Value as Operand in "Not equal to" Expression

Tags: c++, arrays

First time posting so apologies if my form is not ideal, and I appreciate any constructive feedback. Is it possible to use an array size as follows

> if(bedroomsNeeded != apartment[x][y].bedroomsNum)

within the following code:

```
struct Apartment{
    int bedroomsNum;
    int bathroomsNum;
    int rent; };
int main(){
    const int BEDROOMS = 3;
    const int BATHROOMS = 2;
    Apartment apartment[BEDROOMS][BATHROOMS] = {
        {650,0},     /* 1 bedroom row: 1 bath column, 2 bath column */
        {829,925},   /* 2 bedroom row: 1 bath column, 2 bath column */ 
        {0,1075}    /* 3 bedroom row: 1 bath column, 2 bath column */
    };
    int isFoundbedrooms = 0;
    int isFoundbathrooms = 0;
    int bedroomsNeeded = 0;
    int bathroomsNeeded = 0;
    int x = BEDROOMS;
    int y = BATHROOMS;
    while(isFoundbedrooms != 1) {
        cout << "How many bedrooms do you want? (Enter 1, 2 or 3)." << endl;
        cin >> bedroomsNeeded;
        if(bedroomsNeeded != apartment[x][y].bedroomsNum) {
            cout << "Sorry - you entered an invalid number of bedrooms needed." << endl;
            cout << " Please enter either 1, 2 or 3." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You entered " << bedroomsNeeded << " bedrooms needed." << endl;
            isFoundbedrooms = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should indent your code to ease our reading and add some blank rows

Comment: Answering your question, I would say yes, however accessing an array of two objects at index 2 is out of bounds, valid indices are 0 and 1, but not 2. That said, it's a bit unclear what your problem is. Also, please replace e.g. user input code with hardcoded values that demonstrate issues when extracting a minimal example.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to accomplish. When you initialize the apartments array, what are the numbers in the initializer list, the rents (you think)?

Comment: Re: Ulrich "1" "2" and "3" should be the _only_ values the user can enter and receive the output in the else statement. Anything else should return the 'invalid' output. At present, all values return the invalid output, so if(bedroomsNeeded != apartment[x][y].bedroomsNum) is apparently not identifying, 0,1,2, or 3 as valid. The intent to is to test if user input matches any of the indices, and is thus a valid input.

Comment: You are not initializing the array properly. Your `Apartment` struct has 3 members, the array `apartment` (which makes little sense BTW) has 6 elements and your initilizer list has 6 values too instead of 18.

Answer (score 0):

You array is defined as `Apartment apartment[BEDROOMS][BATHROOMS]`.  In C++ arrays are zero based index so `Apartment apartment[0][0]` to `Apartment apartment[BEDROOMS - 1][BATHROOMS - 1]` is valid

When you do `apartment[x][y].bedroomsNum` `x = BEDROOMS` and `y = BATHROOMS` which means you are one past then valid indexs of the arrays.

You need to set `x` to a value in the range of `[0, BEDROOMS)` and `y` to something in the range of `[0, BATHROOMS)`

Comment: Thanks folks, some good food for thought! @leJon: I will take you up on that use of the boolean type! as well as the 'better use of whitespace' suggestion. First time using StackOverflow so I didn't want to overdo it with the size of my code paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but you need to take care of your array size...

```
 x = BEDROOMS ;
 y = BATHROOMS ;
```

are out of range if you access the array with `x,y` as indices
try this:

```
 x = BEDROOMS - 1;
 y = BATHROOMS - 1;
```

And if I can give you an advice, don't use `int` as boolean, c++ has a `boolean` type !